# How to avoid the random suffixes in grob names when using ggplotGrob?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I just noticed that whenever I call `ggplotGrob` on a ggplot object, I get different grob names - specifically, different suffixes. This can be an issue for reproducing code when I select and edit a grob by its full name because that name can change with a new run.

For example, `panel.background..rect.6` becomes `panel.background..rect.76` at a second run.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

p <- ggplot(data = iris, 
            aes(x = Sepal.Length, 
                y = Sepal.Width,
                colour = Species)) +
  geom_point()

# First run
g <- grid.force(ggplotGrob(p))
grid.ls(g)
#> layout
#>   background.1-11-12-1
#>   panel.7-5-7-5
#>     grill.gTree.15
#>       panel.background..rect.6

# Second run
g <- grid.force(ggplotGrob(p))
grid.ls(g)
#> layout
#>   background.1-11-12-1
#>   panel.7-5-7-5
#>     grill.gTree.85
#>       panel.background..rect.76
```

I thought that set.seed() would solve the issue but something like this:

```
set.seed(123)
g <- grid.force(ggplotGrob(p))
grid.ls(g)
```

gives also different suffixes at every run.

I understand that `ggplotGrob(x)` is actually `ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x))`, but I could't find/understand any argument in `ggplot_gtable` nor in `ggplot_build` to stop the random suffixes.

I can go around by using regular expression to select the names of the grobs, avoiding the suffix trap, but was wondering if the random suffix naming could be set off somehow.

Comment: There are a bunch of operations that happen at the C library level and it's very likely said library calls care not about the R random seed.

Comment: I have to date seen nothing that indicates that it will stop or that it can be controlled. Using regular expression on the names (or the layout table) is the most recommended way, to my knowledge.